# Accessing DatagramSocket object from Swing button ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, sockets, udp

I am using a swing jFrame to create a GUI for my client-server booking system. I have encountered the problem on the client where I would like to use the DatagramSocket declared in this:

```
public BookingClientUI() throws SocketException {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        initComponents();
        RecvPacket recvProcess = new RecvPacket(clientSocket);
        Thread recvThread = new Thread(recvProcess);
        recvThread.start();
}
```

later on in this button ActionPerformed:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String passwordString = new String(passwordfield.getPassword());
        byte[] passwordBytes = passwordString.getBytes();
        byte[] packetData = new byte[1500];
        packetData = SendPacketHandler.packetConstructor(SendOpcodes.REGISTER_USER,usernamefield.getText(),EncryptionHandler.hashPassword(passwordBytes));
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(packetData,packetData.length,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),9876);
        clientSocket.send(packet);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnknownHostException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BookingClientUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Obviously, the line:

```
        clientSocket.send(packet);
```

has a "cannot find symbol" error as the DatagramSocket that was declared is not in scope. I do not however know how to fix this as I have only been programming in Java for a couple of days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store the socket into a data member of a class that's later accessible to the button handler.  You haven't explained enough about your class hierarchy to say how to do that.  If the button handler is inside `BookingClientUI`, it's simple. You'll have something like:

```
public BookingClientUI() extends JFrame {

  final DatagramSocket clientSocket;

  public BookingClientUI() throws SocketException {
    // Initialize the data member with the open socket.
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
    initComponents();
    RecvPacket recvProcess = new RecvPacket(clientSocket);
    Thread recvThread = new Thread(recvProcess);
    recvThread.start();
  }

  // Any member function can now use clientSocket, including a button action.

}
```

In all this, don't forget that (nearly) all Swing code must run in the UI thread.